# Failing to load the angular directive with in ionic project (plunker included)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am trying to load the register directive inside the ionic project but strangely it doesn't load. Here is the plunker. Please point me in the right direction.

`Example:`https://plnkr.co/edit/7CZq8GRLAMiAQAvnIV2H?p=preview

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your question and put the error output, so people don't have to look for it in the plunkr! Make it easier to help you.

Comment: I realized the mistake. it is a syntax error in signup.js. Thank you.